# How can I fix a migration input format mess?

Tags: 8, migrations, input-formats

I did a migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8 and now I have two *Full HTML*, two *Plain text*, and all other individual for both versions of Drupal default text formats. Of course when I try to modify the duplicates I have warning that it is not possible to have the same human readable names so I have *Full HTML* and *Full HTML2* now. I want to get rid the one of them. It looks like that all the migrated by me content is with a text format with a machine name 2 while the other Full HTML text format with no any content in the website is with the machine name *full_html*. Also the default Plain Text, the one that it is not possible to be removed is with a machine name 3.

As far as understand by the research I did, even if I disable the *full_html* text format, I cannot use its machine name for the other one. I don't mind what the name is, but can I safely change somehow the text format machine name 2 to something more meaningful?

Is it necessary to do so, or it will be fine if I leave it this way and just remove the *full_html* one as far as I do not need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is in the migration template, to add the input format value.

I found the `default_value` plugin worked well there e.g, to set default `full_html`:

```
field_subheading:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_subheading
  process:
    value: value
    format:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: full_html
```

Another option, could be to run an SQL query to update the field data and revision data tables

```
update node__field_subheading set field_subheading_format = 'full_html' where field_subheading_format = 'other_format';
update node_revision__field_subheading set field_subheading_format = 'full_html' where field_subheading_format = 'other_format';
```

then clear cache.

However fixing as part of the migration template mapping is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, sorry if I am asking something obvious but I cannot run the migration again because the website has a lot of new content, does this mean that I can forget for the migration template and use the sql queries above to update the machine names?

Comment: it works with the sql query, thank you!